# Warning about void context only with low-precedence short-circuit operators

Tags: perl

I just encountered a situation where `and` and `&&` behave differently with respect to warnings.

Here's the original script with `and`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings 'FATAL' => qw[all];

my $var1;
my $var2;

my $defined = (defined $var1) and (defined $var2);

print ($defined ? "defined\n" : "undefined\n");
```

because first condition is false, the second expression in the and is never evaluated.

```
% perl defined.pl
Useless use of defined operator in void context at defined.pl line 8.
Exit 255
```

However if I change the operation to the higher-precedence but otherwise identical `&&`, I don't get a void context warning.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings 'FATAL' => qw[all];

my $var1;
my $var2;

my $defined = (defined $var1) && (defined $var2);

print ($defined ? "defined\n" : "undefined\n");
```

The program produces the expected result, `"undefined\n"`.

```
% perl defined.pl
undefined
```

`perldoc perlop` suggests that `and` and `&&` should be identical in all respects except for precedence, but does not explicitly state it.

> As alternatives to && and || when used for control flow, Perl provides
>   the and and or operators (see below). The short-circuit behavior is
>   identical. The precedence of "and" and "or" is much lower, however, so
>   that you can safely use them after a list operator without the need
>   for parentheses:

Comment: *"if I change the operation to the lower-precedence but otherwise identical `&&`"* The `&&` operator has a *much higher* precedence than `and`.

Comment: "`perldoc perlop` suggests that `and` and `&&` should be identical in all respects except for precedence, but does not explicitly state it." I'm not sure how much more explicit you want it to be. It clearly says "The precedence of `and` and `or` **is much lower**".

Comment: It doesn't state in the documentation that `undef` is treated the same way by `&&` and `and` with respect to warnings. I thought it was conceivable that they could always return the same values as each other and evaluate their right argument under the same circumstances but interact with warnings differently. I was wrong, but I thought at the time that that was a possibility.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The assignment operator has a [higher precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) than `and`, so

```
my $defined = (defined $foo) and (defined $bar);
```

is equivalent to

```
(my $defined = (defined $foo)) && (defined $bar);
```

You can see this with [B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html):

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'my $defined = (defined $foo) && (defined $bar)'                                                               
my $defined = defined $foo && defined $bar;
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'my $defined = (defined $foo) and (defined $bar)'
defined $bar if my $defined = defined $foo;
-e syntax OK
```